# Transfering items from lists into variables in Python

Tags: python

I have been working on a project, and I just started using python. I have searched all over the web, and found no information. I have to transfer items in list to variables, and I have no clue what to do. If anyone can help, please respond.

Comment: That is very unclear, please provide code, an example of what you tried, and something that we can understand ;)

Comment: Or are you talking about unpacking iterables? `price, quantity = [10, 15]`

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you have a list, `lst = [1, 2, '3', '4']`, all you have to do is `new_var = lst[0]`, or what ever index you want. Now your `new_var` is equal to whatever was in the list index, in this case, `1`.

Comment: Regarding the answer, no ones understoof the problem the same, not even me the question is just unclear. Please don't rush to provide an answer "just in case it's what what is expected".

Comment: It sure sounded like he didn't know how to assign list items to a variable to me, and that's what my answer explains.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Values in the list:
lst = [1, 2, 3]

# Transfer to variables to get these values:
# a = 1, b = 2, c = 3
a, b, c = lst
```

Answer (score -2):

If I understand your problem correctly, there is a list

```
list = ["a","s","c","v"]
```

You want to add it to a data frame

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'Col 1': [1, 2, 3,7]})
```

You can add it directly to the data frame by giving a variable name

```
dataframe["Col 2"] = list
```

Comment: Regarding the answer, no ones understoof the problem the same, not even me the question is just unclear. Please don't rush to provide an answer "just in case it's what what is expected".

Comment: there is no mention about data frames?

Comment: @azro I don't see as to why a negative vote should be added for that reason. You are free to not engage

Comment: 1. I did not downvote 2. Why do people complain about downvotes ? That’s the game , you answer and if sienne is unhappy with it , he can downvote, same for upvote ;)